# How to return n number of rows for each value in one specific column in Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Started learning Pandas just yesterday.

I've created a DataFrame with columns 'category', 'uid', 'sales' and some other columns which schematically looks like this:

```
    category    uid sales
0    Grocery     1   XX
1    Grocery     2   XX
2    Sports      3   XX
3    Grocery     4   ZZ
4    Beauty      5   ZZ
5    Beauty      6   ZZ
6    Sports      7   ZZ
7    Grocery     8   ZZ
...
```

My DataFrame has thousands of rows, and I need only n number of rows for each value in category column. Let this number be 20. I've searched for answer but couldn't find anything.

Comment: `df.groupby('category').head(n=20)`

Comment: Also, for newer Pandas (1.1.0+), you can use [groupby().sample()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.sample.html) for random sampling: `df.groupby('category').sample(n=20)`.

Comment: @QuangHoang It works perfectly. Easy and brilliant solution. Thank you.